# General Term For Getting Property Of A Nullable Object

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

Considering the JavaScript below:

```
var foo = undefined;
if(foo?.bar == true){
    console.log("Wow. Impossible...");
}
```

Is there a general programming term for the `?.` following the foo variable?

This allows you to compare a member of a potentially null object without having to explicitly check if the variable is null.

I'd like to be able to see if this functionality exists in other languages, but I'm not really sure *what* to look up.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

Answer (score 1):

It is known as Optional Chaining in JS.

Ref:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining
2. https://javascript.info/optional-chaining

It is known differently in different languages, e.g. in C# it is called Null-Conditional.